# Use Drive API through a service account using GCE Metadata server at GCP Compute server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-compute-engine

Have been successfully accessing files through the Drive API using a service account with access to those Drive files, by using the regular authentication with the .json credentials.

Now, we want to remove the usage of .json credentials and rely on the GCE Metadata server, as per described here [https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#:~:text=When%20running%20in%20GCP%2C%20service%20authorize%20is%20automatically%20provided%20via%20the%20GCE%20Metadata%20server](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#:%7E:text=When%20running%20in%20GCP%2C%20service%20authorize%20is%20automatically%20provided%20via%20the%20GCE%20Metadata%20server). But I keep getting an `Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.` error, even though I'm setting the scopes the same way I was doing with the .json credentials, where the requests were successful.

The Node.js code that I'm using is:

```js
const google = require('@googleapis/drive') // v2.0.2

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({ scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] })
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth })

await drive.files.create(...)
```

Is it possible to access the Drive API using GCE Metadata tokens?

Comment: Which Compute Engine VM scopes do you have enabled?

Comment: The VM where I'm testing this has `Cloud API access scopes` -> `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`.

Comment: Edit your question and include your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, confirm that the service account identity (email address) has permission to access Google Drive at Google Drive.

Comment: Docs for settings Compute Engine scopes: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-service-account You will need to stop the instance to change scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access Drive, 2 conditions must be met:

1. The service account must be granted access to Drive
2. The VM must have been created with `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

I suspect you've missed (2). Note that *Allow full access to all Cloud APIs* doesn't include Drive since Drive isn't a Google Cloud API.

Comment: That worked, thanks! For the record the CLI command I used was `gcloud compute instances set-service-account INSTANCE_NAME --scopes=cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --zone=ZONE`